# How to create a table from a schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called tbRep in my database

I have 3 schemas on the the SQL Server database 
X, Y, Z

now X & Y have tables called X.tbRep & Y.tbRep

However, when I try use the CREATE To script from e.g. X.tbRep and try to create one for the new schema Z, it throws an error saying,

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
>   There is already an object named 'tbRep' in the database.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm sure that there are Z.tbRep doesn't exist

> CREATE to script

```
USE [Info]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Z].[tbRep](
[ReplicaGroup] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[RunFrequencyUnit] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
[LastRun] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[RunFrequency] [int] NOT NULL,
[ReplicationWindowType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[ReplicationWindowSize] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbReplicaGroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ReplicaGroup] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [Z].[tbReplicaGroups] ADD  CONSTRAINT    [DF_tbReplicaGroups_ReplicationWindowType]  DEFAULT ('D') FOR [ReplicationWindowType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Z].[tbReplicaGroups] ADD  CONSTRAINT  [DF_tbReplicaGroups_ReplicationWindowSize]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [ReplicationWindowSize]
GO
```

Comment: Can you show your actual create statement? And did you validate that the schema `Z` doesn't already have such a table? If you right-clicked `X.tbRep` and said `Script To >` you need to change `[X]` to `[Z]`.

Comment: And are you absolutely certain there's no `Z.tbRep`? A failed attempt might have left such a table.

Comment: there's no Z.tbRep. I have posted the code too

Comment: try select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES what does it show?

Comment: or better this :  select * from sys.all_objects where name = 'tbRep' - how many rows does it return?

Comment: the select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES showed that there was a VIEW with that name Z.tbRep I removed the View and rand the script again, and it worked. Thanks Zar, you made my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

--Checks to see if the table doesn't already exist, if not add your creation script
if not exists (select name from sys.tables where name = 'tpRep')
BEGIN
--Table Creation code goes here
END

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute this before CREATE TABLE statement and let us know if you are getting anything?

```
select * 
from sys.all_objects 
where sys.all_objects.name = 'tbRep' and 
sys.all_objects.type = 'U' and
sys.all_objects.schema_id = (select schema_id from sys.schemas where sys.schemas.name = 'Z')
```